# Using xsl:element tag for html transformation

Tags: html, xslt, tags

I'm transforming xsl document to html like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Title</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        Blah-blah
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Is it right way? Or, maybe, using of `xsl:element` is better? I didn't saw examples with such variant:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
      <xsl:element name="head">
        <xsl:element name="title">
          Title
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="body">
        Blah-blah
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Which variant is right? 
 Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A literal result element (i.e. your first approach) is shorter, easier to type and easier to read. I would suggest to use `xsl:element` only in cases where you want to compute the element name and/or namespace dynamically based on input data e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

In other cases I would use literal result elements as in your first sample. But there is no right or wrong in terms of the result, both variants give the same result tree.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about this case (element name computing). Thank you, It's more clear for me now!